# Reference on Geometric Invariant Theory

Tags: reference-request, geometric-invariant-theory

I am currently self-learning Geometric Invariant Theory on Mumford book, but found it is really hard to me. Is there any good reference for self-study? (Algebraic geometry flavour is better, although I accept symplectic quotient.) Thank you.